# Can I use Revo Uninstaller to remove programs from drive D (it's not a partition of C)

Tags: windows-10, uninstall

The "MAIN" screen of Revo Uninstaller (Free is the version I'm using) lists all the programs on my computer...but I checked (by right-clicking the names of them all in the first column) and all the programs listed seem to be installed on C drive.

I know, by using File Explorer (or whatever it's called now) that my D drive (it's a discreet, second, physical hard drive in my desktop PC) has programs located in a separate Program folder also.

How can I (or, CAN I) use Revo to uninstall any of THESE programs?

Comment: Where in Revo do you see the installation folder?

Comment: Open the app. You'll see a table of all the programs installed. The first column is the apps names. Next is their size. Then version.....etc.
Just RIGHT CLICK on any of the names....in the first column.....and you'll get a popup menu.
The sixth option down in this little drop-down/pop-up menu is Install Location.
If you left-click on THAT, it literally opens a File Explorer window showing you the location of the program and the path for getting there.

Comment: But there is no installation folder (and cannot be, since there might be multiple folders). Are you sure that you are using [Revo Uninstaller Freeware](https://www.revouninstaller.com/)?

Comment: Yup. Can I put a screenshot in here?

Comment: Of course, go ahead.

Comment: I guess what I meant to ask is "HOW can I put a screenshot in here?" :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101243/discussion-between-michael-scott-and-harrymc).
Did you lose track of me, Harry? I converted to a chat....

Comment: Harry. What happened? You still there? I guess harry gave up.

Comment: Hey, I'm not attached to the computer screen... :; But there is still no installation folder in the screenshot.

Comment: Why don't you try with one product, with Revo on maximum scan, and see?

Comment: Did that. No programs that are visible on the D drive (in Windows/File Explorer) show up on the Revo 'main' screen. And none of the programs that DO show up on the main screen display D: as their "Install Location" when you right click on them. 
So I assume that either 1. Revo cannot address any drive location OTHER than C:......or, 2. There's a setting, somewhere in Revo, that I'm not finding/seeing.

Comment: To answer your question another way....I've tried to uninstall programs from my D drive using Revo.
Can't find them.

Comment: Add another screenshot of the ones on D. I could have at look tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks, Harry. I'll watch for you tomorrow.

Comment: You still around, Harry? Did you see my second screenshot?

Comment: Sorry, was distracted by other things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that there are installed products that don't show up in Revo,
although you can see their folder on the disk.
This is normal in our software jungle on Windows.

Not every product has an installer, some just create their folders and icons.
Windows cannot know about products about which it was never notified,
so Revo cannot know about them either.

Some of those products are relatively well-behaved, in the sense that they supply
an uninstall executable in their folder, where you have to search for an `.exe`
file that includes the string "uninstall" in its name (unless the author got
too creative).

Some other products don't offer any automatic aid for their installation,
and require special treatment, which consists of:

- Search all the disks for folders that contain the product-name.
  I use for that the speedy [Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/).
- Search the registry for all mention of the product-name in keys, values and data.
  I use for that
  [Nirsoft RegScanner](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/regscanner.html),
  which speeds registry searches enormously.
  However, great attention and some knowledge is required when deleting items.
  It is better to at least create a System Restore point before modifying the
  registry, so to be able to go back on an unfortunate delete.

If you are installing products of whom you are unsure and may decide in the
future to erase, then they are better installed in a sandbox, isolated from
the main disk and the registry. Cleaning out the sandbox gets rid of them
completely without any effort or uninstallation.
For that I use [Sandboxie](https://www.sandboxie.com/), rather than the new
and too basic
[Microsoft Sandbox](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Windows-Kernel-Internals/Windows-Sandbox/ba-p/301849).

Comment: Fabulous, Harry. Thanks for the very detailed/explicit guidance. (Happy New Year, BTW. Sorry it took so long to respond!) Cheers!